# rails3 disable spinner for particular ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, spinner

My project having lot of ajax links and I might to implement spinner for every ajax request.
I have used ajaxStart and ajaxStop callbacks globally in my application.js for all ajax request.

my application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(this).ajaxStart(function(){
     $("#ajax_loader").modal('show');
   })
   .ajaxStop(function(){
     $("#ajax_loader").modal("hide");
   });

});
```

but some pages has lot of quick small ajax calls and **spinner is not needed for some ajax links which has** `data-spinner = false` **attribute**.

I traveled web and found some solution(unbind) which doesn't fit my requirement. For example

index.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(this).unbind("ajaxStart ajaxStop")
   });
</script>

<%= link_to "show", xxx, :remote => true, "data-spinner" => true %>

<%= link_to "update", xxx, :remote => true, "data-spinner" => false %>

<%= link_to "remove", xxx, :remote => true, "data-spinner" => false %>
```

**unbind** will disable the spinner for all ajax calls available in the page.

appriciate any idea or solution ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the ajax:before to the element that you want, in [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax). [See this article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/05/11/jquery-ujs-and-jquery-trigger.html)

You can target the element having data-spinner like this

```
$('a[data-remote=true][data-spinner=true]').on('ajax:before', function(){
  $("#ajax_loader").modal('show');
})

$('a[data-remote=true][data-spinner=true]').on('ajax:complete', function(){
  $("#ajax_loader").modal("hide");
})
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

You can keep a check for all `remote => 'true'` links if it has the `data-spinner` attribute.

```
$('a[data-remote=true]').on('ajax:before', function(){

   var nospinner = false;

   if($(this).attr('data-spinner') != undefined && $(this).attr('data-spinner') == "false"){
      nospinner = true;
    }

    if(nospinner==false) {
      $("#ajax_loader").modal('show');
    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. sorry! So far I haven't used "data-spinner" => true attribute in my ajax link. Due to lot of ajax links, I plan to apply "data-spinner" => false to only those links which I don't want ajax spinner? any solution?

Comment: I have updated the answer with your requirement. Hope that helped. Also it would be better if you give a data attribute to all links on which you want the spinner to be shown so that you can bind the ajax:before to that specific element only.

Comment: @anpsmn if we are using client_side_validations gem, gem will make ajax request for validate uniqness, how to show spinner for this case ?

Comment: @nishanthan Can you give the url for the gem? Is [this the gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations#callbacks) you are using? If yes then use the callbacks for the spinner.